# which.max outcome in list

Tags: r, max

edit: See solution at the bottom.

I have trouble using the outcome of an which.max outcome in a list.
Below follows an example which reproduces my problem.

Create dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

name <- c('A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 
          'B','B','B', 'B','B','B', 'B','B','B',
          'C','C','C', 'C','C','C', 'C','C','C')
month = c("oct 2018", "oct 2018", "oct 2018","nov 2018", "nov 2018", "nov 2018","dec 2018", "dec 2018", "dec 2018",
         "oct 2018", "oct 2018", "oct 2018","nov 2018", "nov 2018", "nov 2018","dec 2018", "dec 2018", "dec 2018" ,
         "oct 2018", "oct 2018", "oct 2018","nov 2018", "nov 2018", "nov 2018","dec 2018", "dec 2018", "dec 2018" )
value <- seq(1:length(month))

df = data.frame(name, month, value)
df
```

Outcome

```
name    month   value
A   oct 2018    1
A   oct 2018    2
A   oct 2018    3
A   nov 2018    4
A   nov 2018    5
A   nov 2018    6
A   dec 2018    7
A   dec 2018    8
A   dec 2018    9
B   oct 2018    10
B   oct 2018    11
B   oct 2018    12
B   nov 2018    13
B   nov 2018    14
B   nov 2018    15
B   dec 2018    16
B   dec 2018    17
B   dec 2018    18
C   oct 2018    19
C   oct 2018    20
C   oct 2018    21
C   nov 2018    22
C   nov 2018    23
C   nov 2018    24
C   dec 2018    25
C   dec 2018    26
C   dec 2018    27
```

Extract name of the observation with the largest value

```
memberLargestValue = df[which.max(df$value),]$name
memberLargestValue
```

Outcome

```
[1] C
Levels: A B C
```

Merge memberLargestValue with pre-existing list

```
oldList = c("A", "A")
newList  = c(oldList, memberLargestValue)
newList
```

Outcome

```
[1] "A" "A" "3"
```

I do not want the "3" in the above list, but I want "C" instead. Does anybody know how I can acccess the "C" in "memberLargestValue" and get it into the list?

**Solution:**
Change to "character" type:

```
memberLargestValue = as.character(df[which.max(df$value),]$name)
```

Comment: set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the initial `data.frame` call or turn `oldList` into a factor with the same levels or split the difference and coerce `memberLargestValue` to character. Also, these are vectors, not lists.

Comment: @alistaire I mangaed it with the character transformation, edited my question to include this solution. Thank you!